# Calculating the average grade from a file

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that reads in grades from a file but the file contains student names and the class they are in as well, some have 3 grades and some have 4. I'm struggling with getting a divide by 0 error when I try to run the program and cant figure it out after much googling, beginner with java. I'm fine with opening the file but I'm struggling with how to get it to read the average of the first line then continue to all the other ones as well returning the value in the println.

File contents(with three grades):

```
//Happy CS145 81 85 91
//Sneezy CS145 67 75 75
//Doc CS145 92 97 89
//Dopey CS111
//Grumpy CS145 75 65 66
//Bashful CS145 81 82 81
//Sleepy CS145 71 74 71
```

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int numTestScores = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int average = 0;
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("PA2data2.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot open file - " + ex);
        }
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            while (input.hasNextInt()){
                sum += input.nextInt();
                numTestScores++;
            } 
            average = sum / numTestScores;
            System.out.println(average);
        }
        System.out.println("Average is " + sum / numTestScores);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to solve these issues is to use that debugger and step through each line.  It's really easy to use.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is to read the `whole` line and then to `split` it - then you can add the three `int` values and divide by `3`

Answer (score 0):

You should use nextLine() rather than nextInt()

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
       String line = input.nextLine();
       String[] brokenLine = line.split(" ");
           //do stuff with your array of {Happy, CS145, 81, 85, 91}
                   ...
                   ...
      }
```

Also, your also going to want to use doubles rather than int for average, you will get average of 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your division operation inside an `if` statement:

```
 if(numTestScores > 0) {
        average = sum / numTestScores;
        System.out.println(average);
 }
```